# Limit of Product description and short description character in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-description

Is there any limit to number of characters for product description and short description in magento 2?

Comment: try this ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_text MODIFY value MEDIUMTEXT;

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237260/how-to-increase-the-length-of-the-product-meta-description-in-magento1-9-when-i

Comment: @Nafisa You want to add limit in database?

Answer (score 0):

> Use Custom Code Try

```
    $sdesc = $_product->getShortDescription();<br ?--> $sdesc = trim($sdesc);
    $limit = 40;
    if (strlen($sdesc) > $limit) {
    $sdesc = substr($sdesc, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc, 0, $limit), ' '));
    }
    echo $sdesc."...";
```